# Only display one entry per day?

Tags: date, entry

I'm trying to make a very simple date based entry page. But I'm just wondering if there's a way to only display one entry per date. So if there's 5 entries for one day and 10 for another, the page should only show the first entry per day?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting with `display_by="day"` . Note that the `limit` parameter will constrain the number of days i guess.. You can add php and/or "if" conditional to check if previous entry was the same day..  maybe using `{entry_date format="%d"}`
You can read the doc -> https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#display-by